# Java IllegalArgumentException when assigning array of buttons to GridLayout

Tags: java, arrays, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

So I have started a calculator from scratch in order to practice Java knowledge.
I have a slight problem, when I'm assigning buttons to a `JLabel` using `GridLayout` the console
returns an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.
I know I am doing something foolish and I better reorganize the array and do a for loop to assign buttons, but I am too lazy to do it and want to understand what I did wrong.

Here is the code:

```
buttonDisplay.setBounds(30, 30, 400, 320); //buttonDisplay is a JLabel
buttonDisplay.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,4,5,5));
        
operator = new JButton[20];
operator[0] = new JButton("0");
operator[1] = new JButton("1");
operator[2] = new JButton("2");
operator[3] = new JButton("3");
operator[4] = new JButton("4");
operator[5] = new JButton("5");
operator[6] = new JButton("6");
operator[7] = new JButton("7");
operator[8] = new JButton("8");
operator[9] = new JButton("9");
operator[10] = new JButton("+");
operator[11] = new JButton("-");
operator[12] = new JButton("*");
operator[13] = new JButton("/");
operator[14] = new JButton(".");
operator[15] = new JButton("=");
operator[16] = new JButton("AC");
operator[17] = new JButton("C");
operator[18] = new JButton("TAX+");
operator[19] = new JButton("TAX-");

buttonDisplay.add(operator[0],4,2); //exception starts on this line
buttonDisplay.add(operator[1],3,3);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[2],3,2);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[3],3,1);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[4],2,3);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[5],2,2);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[6],2,1);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[7],1,3);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[8],1,2);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[9],1,1);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[10],1,4);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[11],2,4);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[12],3,4);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[13],4,4);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[14],4,1);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[15],4,3);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[16],5,1);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[17],5,2);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[18],5,3);
buttonDisplay.add(operator[19],5,4);
```

Comment: Please don't add things like "[SOLVED]" to a question title. Acceptance of an answer is how you mark a question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I ran [part of] your code, the following line threw an exception:

```java
buttonDisplay.add(operator[0],4,2);
```

Here is [part of] the stack trace I got:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1115)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:1033)
```

The method you are calling is this one:
[public void add(Component comp, Object constraints, int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,int))

I assume that you think that the second and third arguments are the row and column positions in the grid – but they are not. `GridLayout` does not provide the ability to indicate row and column when adding a component. I think that [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) is probably a more appropriate layout manager for what you are trying to do.

Also, even though class `javax.swing.JLabel` inherits from class `java.awt.Container`, it is not intended to contain `JButton`s. There are other *Swing* components that are intended for this purpose, such as [javax.swing.JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPanel.html).

So I suggest replacing `JLabel` with `JPanel` and using `GridBagLayout`.

Perhaps the following is more in line with what you are trying to achieve.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Calculat {
    private JTextField  display;

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing JTextField and JPasswordField");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createDisplay(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createButtons(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtons() {
        JPanel buttonDisplay = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        JButton[] operator = new JButton[20];
        operator[0] = new JButton("0");
        operator[1] = new JButton("1");
        operator[2] = new JButton("2");
        operator[3] = new JButton("3");
        operator[4] = new JButton("4");
        operator[5] = new JButton("5");
        operator[6] = new JButton("6");
        operator[7] = new JButton("7");
        operator[8] = new JButton("8");
        operator[9] = new JButton("9");
        operator[10] = new JButton("+");
        operator[11] = new JButton("-");
        operator[12] = new JButton("*");
        operator[13] = new JButton("/");
        operator[14] = new JButton(".");
        operator[15] = new JButton("=");
        operator[16] = new JButton("AC");
        operator[17] = new JButton("C");
        operator[18] = new JButton("TAX+");
        operator[19] = new JButton("TAX-");

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[0], gbc); //exception starts on this line
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[1], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[2], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[3], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[4], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[5], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[6], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[7], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[8], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[9], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[10], gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[11], gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[12], gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[13], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[14], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[15], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[16], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[17], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[18], gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        buttonDisplay.add(operator[19], gbc);
        return buttonDisplay;
    }

    private JPanel createDisplay() {
        JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
        display = new JTextField(16);
        display.setFocusable(false);
        displayPanel.add(display);
        return displayPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculat calc = new Calculat();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> calc.createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

This is what is displayed when running the above code.

[image: screen capture of GUI]

Answer (score 0):

JLabel is not a container it is used to place a plain text or image. but i understand that you need something a container that can hold all the buttons. So, you should use JPanel.
here is the code that helps you a lot.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class Calculator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel();
    JButton operator[] = new JButton[20];
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Calculator();
    }

    public Calculator() {

        operator[0] = new JButton("0");
        operator[1] = new JButton("1");
        operator[2] = new JButton("2");
        operator[3] = new JButton("3");
        operator[4] = new JButton("4");
        operator[5] = new JButton("5");
        operator[6] = new JButton("6");
        operator[7] = new JButton("7");
        operator[8] = new JButton("8");
        operator[9] = new JButton("9");
        operator[10] = new JButton("+");
        operator[11] = new JButton("-");
        operator[12] = new JButton("*");
        operator[13] = new JButton("/");
        operator[14] = new JButton(".");
        operator[15] = new JButton("=");
        operator[16] = new JButton("AC");
        operator[17] = new JButton("C");
        operator[18] = new JButton("TAX+");
        operator[19] = new JButton("TAX-");

        setSize(500, 500);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        buttonContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4,5,5));
        buttonContainer.setBackground(Color.red);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            buttonContainer.add(operator[i]);
        }
        add(buttonContainer);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```